# VPython destroys all tkinter windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, vpython

I am trying to make a simple GUI application that uses VPython for visualization. I am successful in doing so. However, when I close the VPython window, all of my other windows (which I made using Tkinter) closes as well thereby ending the processes of the whole program. I already tried scene.exit = False but id doesn't seem to work.

Please someone help me

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from visual import *
import serial

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("MultiSense(Desktop Version)")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('400x500')

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)


def dist_window():
    windist = tk.Toplevel(root)
    windist.wm_title("Distance Sensor")
    windist.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    windist.geometry('100x150')

    def senseDist():
        scene.title = "Visualization"
        scene.fullscreen = True
        scene.visible = False
        objDist = cylinder(display=scene, length=20, color=color.green, raduis=1, pos=(-20, 0, 0))

        while (1 == 1):
            rate(20)
            if (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
                myData = ser.readline()
                distance = float(myData)
                objDist.length = distance

    btnStart = Button(windist, text="Calculate distance", command=senseDist)
    btnStart.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X)

def doNothing():
    print 'Nothing'

# ******** Main Window ********** #

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
subMenu1 = Menu(fileMenu)
subMenu1.add_command(label="Distance Sensor", command=dist_window)
fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Go to ...', menu=subMenu1, underline=0)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu)
helpMenu.add_command(label="How to use MultiSense", command=doNothing)
helpMenu.add_separator()
helpMenu.add_command(label="About MultiSense", command=doNothing)


root.wm_iconbitmap('windowicon.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

I'm very new to python. I am using Arduino to send the serial data. There are really no errors with this code. I just want to close only the VPython window but it always end up closing the entire program.

Comment: Could you post an "offending", working code sample? Linux?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I already edited my question. By the way I'm working on windows

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it is possible to integrate vpython into tkinter without another external program to extract the values of VPythons screen an example program would be 'PIL'then it would be able to integrate

another way would require the use of python first then html then css/java script, then python again to extract the values